# go back through history skipping the same page

Tags: javascript

So i am using this js code to go back to previous page

```
 function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}


<span onclick="goBack()">back</span>
```

example:

> home > product > product add to cart > click back return to home

now when i add product to cart the page reload and when i click back it return to same page

is there any possible way to make the window.history.back ignore if it return to same page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag in the case of adding a product to the cart and if the flag is true use:

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

Comment: but what if visitor clicked twice on add to cart ?

Comment: Well, I thought of this, then you have to make a counter because this the only workaround with `windows.history` I can think of other than navigating directly to homepage for example so there is no back button but homepage button.